# How can I change font color and font style of ePub Book in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, epub

I have created app of books which supports pdf and ePub format. In that app, pdf is just shown as an image and ePub open in webview because EPUB is just XHTML stored in a zipfile with an XML manifest. Now, I want to change the **font style** and **font color** of ePub book pages. Is it possible? If possible, then how can I achieve this? I have searched a lot, but did not get any proper solution.

Comment: Do you have a way to do the sam in a non mobile browser? (Mac Cocoa webview for instance)

Comment: means you want to develop for mac webview not for iPhone ?

Comment: sorry i have no idea about mac development. but probably it same just minor changes in MAC side development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution. 
I have make a string and evaluate using Java string

This is what I have written:

```
NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
"if (mySheet.addRule) {"
"mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
"} else {"
"ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
"mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
"}"
"}";

NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width];
NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", currentTextSize];
NSString *setHighlightColorRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('highlight', 'background-color: yellow;')"];

    // this is what change the text style 

NSString *insertRule3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html, body, div, p, span, a', 'font-family: arial;')"];
NSString *changeColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html, body, div, p, span, a', 'color: #1122CC;')"];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setHighlightColorRule];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule3];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:changeColor];
```

Comment: here i am rendering the epub in to the uiwebview in portrait mode its loaded the content but in landscape i need to display two page view could u have any idea

Comment: i am using same i am working with landscape mode. shortly share with you

Comment: are u integrating the pagecurl which is similar to iBook because i have working on that part also

Comment: yes i have search lot but not found pretty solution. have you?

Comment: could you send your mailid i will share that part

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15896/discussion-between-cocoa-matters-and-dineshprasanna)