# How to properly change font in ePub (generall html) in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, epub

I follow this solution

[How can I change font color and font style of ePub Book in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814124/how-can-i-change-font-color-and-font-style-of-epub-book-in-ios)

however it doesn't work properly. For example in this piece of html

```
<body>
<div id="HolubiPosta-E-2.html" xml:lang="cs-CZ">
<div class="Z-kladn--grafick--r-me-ek">
  <p class="Nazev para-style-override-3" id="toc_marker-2">Holubí pošta</p>

  <p class="Z-kladn--odstavec para-style-override-4"><span>Už od rána slunce sypalo hlava nehlava zlato.</span></p>
```

it changes font in second paragraph but it doesn't change font in first paragraph.

How to properly change font-family in all html document?

EDIT: This is css adding function I am using

```
NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
"if (mySheet.addRule) {"
"mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
"} else {"
"ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
"mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
"}"
"}";
```

This is how I call it:

```
NSString *setTextFont = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html, body, div, p, span, a', 'font-family: %@;')", m_str_font_name];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextFont];
```

CSS:

```
p.Nazev {
font-family : "Liberation Serif", serif;
font-weight : normal;
font-style : normal;
font-size : 1.33em;
text-decoration : none;
font-variant : normal;
line-height : 1.2;
text-align : center;
color : #0000ff;
text-indent : 0px;
margin : 0px;}

p.para-style-override-3 {
margin-bottom : 28px;
margin-top : 28px;}

p.para-style-override-4 {
text-align : justify;}

div.Z-kladn--grafick--r-me-ek {}
```

Comment: Can you share the CSS rules you're adding?

Comment: It is in mentioned thread, however, I have copy it here.

Comment: I have add css rules. I am sorry I misunderstood what do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. I can confirm that it works on iOS `UIWebView`. Replace 'serif' with whatever `font-family` you'd like.

```
[self.contentView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
             @"var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;for( i=0; i < styleSheets.length; i++ ){for( j=0; j < styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++){var rule = styleSheets[i].cssRules[j]; rule.style['font-family'] = 'serif'}}"];
```

Not the most elegant way but basically it loops through all existing rules and sets the font family.

I guess your problem occurs because the new element-level rule that you add gets overridden by some existing class-level rule defined in the epub css.

Comment: It really solved this very problem, however, it is not universal solution as some other parts of document that were displaying properly stop working now.

Comment: You are right, I need to change font (plus color of the font) in all document that is not ready for general font changing :-(